# How do I change the component from inside a map function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Suppose I have a state in my react component as

```
state={
   a:0,
   b:0
}
```

I also have an array `arr` as a prop coming into this component

```
[{name:"one",category:"a"},{name:"two",category:"b"},{name:"three",category:"a"}]
```

What I want is iterate over this array and check for each value if category is 'a' then increase the value a by 1 in my state, or else if the category is 'b' then increase the value of b by 1 in my state.

What I have done so far:

```
this.props.arr.map(elem =>{ if(elem.category==='a'){ this.setState({ a:this.state.a+1 }) } })
```

Comment: Where is your current attempt?

Comment: ```this.props.arr.map(elem =>{
            if(elem.category==='a'){
                this.setState({
                    a:this.state.a+1
                })
            } 
        })```

Comment: and what's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: Setting state repeatedly within a `map` operation won't be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the array with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object with `a` and `b` keys, increasing their values with each category that matches, then set the new state with those values with *one operation*.

```js
const arr = [{name:"one",category:"a"},{name:"two",category:"b"},{name:"three",category:"a"}];

// Desctructure `a` and `b` from the result of the
// reduce operation
const { a, b } = arr.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // For each iteration destructure `category` from the current object
  // in the array, increase the value in the accumulator
  // that matches that category, and return the accumulator
  // for the next iteration
  const { category } = c;
  ++acc[category];
  return acc;

// Initialise the accumulator with an object
// with `a` and `b` set to zero
}, {a: 0, b: 0 });

console.log(a, b);

// set the state with the new values of `a` and `b`
// this.setState({ a, b });
```

Answer (score 1):

lets say that your array from props comes with a name of 'array'

```
this.props.array.map(item => {
  if (item.category === 'a') {
    this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 1 });
  } else if (item.category === 'b') {
    this.setState({ a: this.state.b + 1 });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lodash you do countBy like this:

```
const arr = [{name:"one",category:"a"},{name:"two",category:"b"},{name:"three",category:"a"}];

const {a, b} = _.countBy(a,"category")
// set the state with the new values of `a` and `b`
// this.setState({ a, b });
```